# Script to monitor and alert for new orphaned pids

Tags: shell-script, scripting, monitoring, aix

How would you go about detecting and alerting about newly orphaned pids? I would like to cron a script that checks once a day for any orphaned pids (PPID = 1) for a specific user and only alert if a new orphaned process has been detected.

e.g ps -efa output grepping for orphaned pids for "user"

day 1

```
   user  1111111        1   0   Dec 18      -  0:00 command <--- send email about this pid
```

day 2

```
   user  1111111        1   0   Dec 18      -  0:00 command
   user  2222222        1   0   Dec 14      -  0:00 command <--- send email about this pid
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. A [comment to my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/683136/286615) below indicates that you actually were asking about how to create alerts from an analysis of a log of the daily `cron` output. If you can confirm that's actually what you want, I'll add that in an edit tomorrow.

Comment: Re `alerting about newly orphaned pids` & the subsequent reference `<--- send email...`: Could you please clarify what sort of `alert` might work here? If **email** is what you need, do you have an SMTP server set up? Is the mail to be strictly a local message, or (for example) a gmail account?

Answer (score 1):

I'll treat this as in two-steps: 1. detecting the orphan(s), 2. set an alert when a new orphan(s) is found.

#### 1. Detecting the orphan(s)

You may start with something like this:

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,ruser,stat,command
```

This will give you a table listing all processes with a header for the 5 outputs listed here (pid,ppid,ruser,stat,command). Please refer to the section `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS` of `man ps` for a description of these 5 output fields.

Successive pipes of the output to `grep` may be used to filter the list, or `awk` may be more efficient to capture the desired processes; e.g:

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,ruser,stat,command | awk '{ if ($2 == 1 && $3 == "pi") print $0 "\n";}'
  926     1 pi       Ss   /lib/systemd/systemd --user
```

Here, `awk` prints the entire line/record (`$0`) of any line of the `ps` output **IF** the second field (`$2`) has a `ppid` of `1`, **AND** the third field (`$3`) is a string for a user (`pi` in this case). Running this on my system yielded the result shown above.

But now it gets *tricky*... AFAIK, there is no value of the `stat` field that by and of itself identifies an ***orphan*** process; i.e. a process whose parent process has died, but has been adopted by the `init` process - whose `pid` = 1. You may inspect the `PROCESS STATE CODES` section of `man ps` to review the possible values of the `stat` field. A value of "**Z**" indicates Zombie process - which is [similar to an orphan, but different](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/zombie-and-orphan-processes-in-linux).

In summary then, `ps` cannot tell us definitively whether or not a process is an orphan, and so we must regard the output of the command above as a ***list of suspects*** to be further investigated.

Depending upon your users and your system, you may be able to *eliminate* some processes based on the value of the `stat` code, or the `command` field. For example, the command above found a process (`systemd`) with `stat`=`Ss`; this process is not an orphan. AFAICT, the 5 parameters being output from the `ps` command above provide a reasonable basis for meeting your objectives.

#### 2. Set an alert when a new orphan(s) is found

Following is the proposed *approach* to setting an alert using the **orphan detection** command in step 1. above.

Two (2) files will be used: `OrphansOfRecord`, and `OrphansOfTheDay`.
OrphansOfTheDay will be generated as follows:

```bsh
ps -eo pid,ppid,ruser,stat,command | awk '{ if ($2 == 1 && $3 == "pi") print $0 "\n";}' > OrphansOfTheDay
```

Once generated, each line of `OrphansOfTheDay` is compared with each line of `OrphansOfRecord`; i.e. for each line in `OrphansOfTheDay`:

- If that line is NOT found in `OrphansOfRecord`, it is a NEW Orphan, and the Alarm is set.
- If there are no NEW Orphans, the alarm is not set; i.e. no alarm for cleared Orphans

A NEW Orphan process is defined as follows:

- The `pid` is new **OR** the `command` is new

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$5]b[$1];} !($5 in a)||!($1 in b){print "ALERT" > "alertfile"; close ("alertfile")}' OrphansOfRecord OrphansOfTheDay
```

Parsing this `awk` command:

- `NR == FNR` is a *condition* in `awk` - a condition that evaluates TRUE while the *first file* listed in the arguments is being read - `OrphansOfRecord` in this case. The condition evaluates FALSE after reading the first file.
- While, `NR == FNR` is true, the *action* `{a[$5]b[$1];}` is executed. This action stores the values of field `$5` (`command`) and `$1` (`pid`) from each line in `OrphansOfRecord` in the arrays `a` and `b`, respectively. For example, if there are 3 lines (or records) in the `OrphansOfRecord` file, then `a` & `b` will each contain 3 elements when this command is completed.
- After reading all the lines in `OrphansOfRecord`, `NR == FNR` becomes false, and `awk` begins reading the second file `OrphansOfTheDay`. After the first line of `OrphansOfTheDay` is read, the 2nd *condition* is evaluated: `!($5 in a)||!($1 in b)`. This condition compares the `$5` value from that line against the values in array `a`, and the `$1` value from the same line against the values in the array `b`. Note that the *condition* tests for ***no match*** of `$5` in `a` ***or*** a ***match*** of `$1` in `b`.
- This continues as `awk` tests each line of `OrphansOfTheDay`. When the 2nd *condition* is TRUE, the 2nd *action* is executed: `{print "ALERT" > "alertfile"; close ("alertfile")}`. This action creates `alertfile` if it does not already exist by redirecting the `print "ALERT"` to `alertfile` & then closing it to ensure the output buffer is flushed.

The "ALERT" output may be used to signal that a new, suspected Orphan has been found. The presence of `alertfile` - or its contents "ALERT" - may be used to determine if an email needs to be sent.

At this point, `OrphansOfTheDay` has been processed, and an "ALERT" has been created if a suspected Orphan was found. Two things remain to be done:

1. Write `OrphansOfTheDay` to `OrphansOfRecord`:

```
mv OrphansOfTheDay OrphansOfRecord
```

2. If an "ALERT" was set, an email is sent & `alertfile` is cleared:

```
if [ -e alertfile ] 
then 
   mail -s "ALERT: NEW ORPHAN FOUND" pi < OrphansOfRecord 
   rm alertfile
fi
```

Xmas is calling, and I'm out of time for a few days. I'll put the script together asap - or you may proceed on your own.

Comment: The problem is that if this is run through cron, it will need to store PID results from previous runs and compare them. The OP already knows how to identify the orphans (PPID will be 1, so the trick is finding _new_ ones), but cron will run the script and exit so there is no way to compare with previous runs unless you store them in a text file which is read by the script on startup.

Comment: @terdon: I did not get that the OP knew how to id the orphans... you can't rely on PPID=1 exclusively. But yeah - I can add something to redirect the `cron` output to a file.

Comment: No, of course, but if you get those with PPID==1 on the first run, that should include the things actually started by the init, so any new ones with PPID==1 are the ones to look out for. Also, I think it will be a relatively safe bet that any processes belonging to the target user and not root with PPID==1 will be the orphans.

Comment: @terdon: Yeah, maybe :)  It's late here, so I'll edit this answer tomorrow & leave a Comment for the OP.

Comment: @Seamus You can add to ps the `etime` field (if available), and only show processes that are older than 24 hours (if it's a daily cron). Or, if `etime` is not available, you can add `lstart` field and parse it to reach the same solution. In addition you can add to ps `--ppid 1` so you won't need to check the ppid in your `awk` command.

Comment: On a second though etime or lstart won't help, in case the process is running for a long time and only became orphan in the last 24 hours.

Comment: @aviro: wrt `etime`: Yes, the `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS` section in `man ps` has a variety of *keywords* for establishing time. Re `--ppid 1` vs `awk`: Yes, that *may be* more efficient, but I feel that `awk` provides a *more flexible* approach - useful in situations where one is not quite certain which parameters might be useful.  It's also why I favor `-eo` - but I'm new to `ps`, so my opinions are still in flux.

Comment: hello, i can identify and get a list of the orphaned pids in questions. its just trouble sending alerts about new ones popping up. i dont want to spam emails of pids that i've known that have been orphaned already.

i was initially thinking of doing something like @aviro's suggestion of using etime but discovered that the process could also become an orphan after 24hrs and it will get missed.

but yeah, i think the script will need to compare a file of previously orphaned pids in order to identify new ones. i am just stumped at how to go about this.

the alerts are just an email alert

Comment: @jonske: OK, thanks for following up. I'm going to post a revision in a few moments with the rest of my proposed logic for setting the alarms. I've not put all the code in a script & dealt with `cron` details yet, but I think there are enough details here to give you a pretty clear idea of where I'm going. Please do me a favor & review & comment. If it won't meet your needs, there's no point in spending more time on it. Thnx.

Comment: @jonske: Edit posted

Comment: @Seamus thanks, yes this is looking like what i want to do. so i will use `ps -e -o pid,ppid,user,args | awk '{ if ($2 == 1 && $3 == "user" && $4 == "command") print $0;}' > OrphansOfTheDay ` to generate the daily listing of orphaned pids. can you explain what `awk 'NR == FNR{a[$5]b[$1];} !($5 in a)||!($1 in b)' OrphansOfRecord OrphansOfTheDay` is doing?

Comment: also a new orphan would only be a new `pid` the `command` will always be the same

Comment: @jonske: Yes, I can explain it, I'll add something to my answer. But probably a better explanation is in [this Q&A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-are-nr-and-fnr-and-what-does-nr-fnr-imply).

Comment: @jonske: Not certain I understand your 2nd comment, but let me say this: AFAIK, a PID can be re-used; certainly it can be re-used between boots. IIRC, my thinking was this: A rare, perhaps impossible, situation, but it was so easy to add & it might be a fail-safe? IOW, A new command could => new orphan, same PID, and an "old" command could => new orphan, different PID. The `OrphansOfRecord` file persists between boots - at least that was my thinking - you??

Comment: @jonske: I've taken this as far as I can for now; I've been told Xmas takes priority for the next week. I'll put the script together when I return, or feel free to pursue that on your own.